# Why can't I read input values with Chinese characters in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode

I pass a value like '測試' to my form, and I get back the value by doing this:

```
$this->input->post('field_name');
```

I find that I can't get back the '測試' value, I get nothing.

My version is 2.0.2, and the `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';`

If I `echo('測試')`, there is no problem.

With Latin characters it works, and prints perfectly. How can I solve it?

Code From the form:

The form

```
<form target="sc_light_box" action='http://localhost:8888/my_project/index.php/data/add_data.php' method="post">
<textarea id="field_name" name="field_name"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit_button">
</form>
```

The controller:

```
public function add_data()
{
       $this->_load_add_data_page();    
}  


private function _load_add_data_page()
{   
    $this->load->library('form_validation');  
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->helper('form'); 

    $data['field_name']              =$this->input->post('field_name');


    $this->load->view('add_data_page_view', $data);    
}
```

The view:

> ```
>       <?php echo $field_name?>
> ```

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: I got nothing....my version is 2.0.2, and the $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; I just simple echo the value, if I echo('測試'), there is no problems.

Comment: Does it work if you try it with Latin characters?

Comment: yp, it works, and print perfectly.

Comment: @Ted, Would you show us your actual code please? Are you running form validation on the input before reading the value? Some string manipulation functions, even native to PHP, may be causing you to lose or alter the value.

Comment: Ted, what does `var_dump($_POST)` give you after submitting the form? Add it to your post, it's not apparent why this would happen from what you've provided so far unless you are attempting to read the value before it's been posted...

Comment: @@" It is strange, it get nothing .... That's mean the .php file get nothing:

Comment: I am also having similar problem. I can submit the form with Latin characters perfectly, however unicode characters get ignored or gets empty.

Comment: Raf, I solved it. Check the answer. :)

Comment: @Ted - your solution wasn't pleasing as I required it to be secure and done through server side. I managed to check the issue and noticed that changing the charset value to simple letters have worked for me. Please see the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, you need to 
use the javascript encodeURI function to encodeURI the data, before u post.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue by updating the config file charset value to simple letters.

Before it was

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

and I changed it to :

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```

Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

set charset in config file as below-

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```

Then use following header at top of the page in which pageyou need to show/print/input your unicode text-

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You can set this header in general into your index page as well.